# Calculation With VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am attempting to do a calculation in SQL Server 2008 R2 but I keep getting an error of

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.05' to data type int.

Altering table structure is not an option, is there a way I can alter the query so that this will succesfully execute?

```
DECLARE @Test1 TABLE
(
  field1 VARCHAR(10),
  field2 INT
);

INSERT INTO @Test1 ( field1, field2 )
    VALUES ( '.05', 12 );

SELECT field1 / field2 
FROM @Test1;
```

Comment: Why is altering the table structure not an option? Whose decision was it to store numbers in a string column? What is preventing non-numbers from being introduced into that column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Table variables are forever.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Well, I assume that's just the MVCE and that in real life Yohan has a real table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Probably. I see the varchar field for decimals pretty often when weird numbers that end up as scientific notation on insert start happening.

Comment: These are the reasons we'll have work for a *long time*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want to happen?

```
DECLARE @Test1 TABLE
(
  field1 VARCHAR(10),
  field2 INT
);

INSERT INTO @Test1 ( field1, field2 )
    VALUES ( '.05', 12 );

SELECT field1 / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), field2)
    FROM @Test1;
```

Since this was marked as the answer: I converted the integer value to a decimal because of [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). The string '.05' can't be converted to an integer, but it makes a perfectly fine decimal.

Comment: You may want to add some details about why you chose 18,2.  I know I'd like to know.

Comment: @MaxVernon only because the one example decimal was two places. The project specs were pretty slim ;)